# Firebase Cloud Functions send notification weird output

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm create a function like this to send Notification to new user.

```
exports.sendCreateSuccessNotification = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newVal = snap.data();
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Create Account Success",
        body: "Hello " + newVal.emailUser
      }
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(newVal.notiToken, payload);
  });
```

The output is have the error line 
[image]
But my device received the notification.

When I changed the code to below that have a return

```
exports.sendCreateSuccessNotification = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newVal = snap.data();
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Create Account Success",
        body: "Hello " + newVal.emailUser
      }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(newVal.notiToken, payload);
  });
```

The output have no error but my device not get any notification. 
[image]
Can anyone explain it to me please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, and you can read about this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

For Firestore (and all background) functions, you must return a promise that resolves only after all the asynchronous work is complete in the function.  Sending a notification is asynchronous, since [sendToDevice](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice) returns a promise.  By returning that promise, you are signaling to Cloud Function that all its work is done, and it's safe to clean up.

Comment: I didn't know that. Tks for the information. How can we put await for `sendToDevice`. I tried async and await but can't.

Comment: That sounds like it should be a whole new question.

Comment: I figured it out with Async and Await. The problem is I can't use it before. After add "engine: node 8" and it work